# Can't delete iCloud account from Mail, Contacts, Calendars

Tags: macos, icloud, mail.app

When trying to log into iCloud from System Preferences, I'm told

> [appleid] is already signed in to iCloud
>
> To use this as your primary iCloud account, delete it from Mail, Contacts, 
>   and Calendars and sign in again.

However, I can't delete the account from Mail, Contacts and Calendars.  When I go to that preference pane, I'm prompted for my iCloud password, after which I'm told the account isn't verified.  Checking at http://appleid.apple.com shows that the account *is* verified. Requesting that another verification email be sent is met with the following error:

> Couldn't request a new verification email because of a server error.

Any ideas how to delete the account from Mail, Contacts and Calendars? I've deleted all other mail accounts. Removed the mail folders and plist files from `~/Library/`. Rebooted.  Tried adding a different apple id.  Tried everything I could find from Google that looked even close.  No luck.  Help!

Comment: Quite a bit overboard, but reloading your computer would likely nail the computer part of the problem - if all else fails. More realistically, I would call Apple, and see if they can work through the Apple ID problem with you - especially since you can't get a confirmation email sent. It sounds more like an Apple ID problem then just your computer giving you trouble.

Comment: What happens when you go to the System Preferences pane of iCloud and click Sign Out?

Comment: I can't sign out -- the button isn't available -- because I'm not signed in.  When I try to sign in, I get the "...is already signed in..." message in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by turning off all sharing (the checkbox options on the right of the panel), THEN trying to delete again.